# XPath Invalid Selector Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, selenium

I can't see why I get an invalid selector error in my XPath syntax here:

The given selector `/*/tbody[@id='custContainer']/tr/td/a(starts-with(@href, 'Customers/')` is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
[InvalidSelectorError] Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression `/*/tbody[@id='dgContainer']/tr/td/a(starts-with(@href, 'Customers/')` because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "resource://fxdriver/modules/atoms.js Line: 2398"]

This is a call I'm doing in Selenium using By.XPath.  I also tried // instead of /*/ for the start of that path but not sure which to use...not sure of that's the problem or if it's some other part of my string here.

I also tried contains instead of starts-with.

FYI I'm new to Selenium and XPath....

Comment: Simplify. Every time I struggle with XPath I start with the broadest query possible to ensure I get results and then refine. Start with /*/tbody and incrementally add on.

Comment: Probably you need `a[starts-with(@href, 'Customers/')]` (note the square brackets)

Comment: thanks for the advice n8wl, I'm starting to see that too.  I don't really know exactly how XPath works...it makes sense but I have to get used to how it walks the dom, what it expects, etc.

Comment: You seem to be relying on trial and error. Not a good strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely your XPath expression is incorrect. Define predicate in square brackets, i.e.:

```
/*/tbody[@id='custContainer']/tr/td/a[starts-with(@href, 'Customers/')]
```

Comment: Here's the final xpath string that worked for me string.Format("//tbody[@id='custContainer']/tr/td/a[(contains(@href, '{0}'))]", "/Customer/"));